# Chromium build gclient runhooks error number 13

Tags: python, build, permissions, chromium

I am getting the following error while running gclient runhooks for building chromium.

> running '/usr/bin/python src/tools/clang/scripts/update.py --if-needed' in '/media/usrname/!!ChiLL out!!'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "src/tools/clang/scripts/update.py", line 283, in 
>       sys.exit(main())
>
> File "src/tools/clang/scripts/update.py", line 269, in main
>       stderr=os.fdopen(os.dup(sys.stdin.fileno())))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
>       return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception
>
> OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
>   Error: Command /usr/bin/python src/tools/clang/scripts/update.py --if-needed returned non-zero exit status 1 in /media/usrname/!!ChiLL out!!

In order to get permission of the directory "/usr/bin/python src/tools/clang/scripts" I tried chown and chmod but it returned the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the directory was not mounted with execution permission. So I remounted the directory with execution permission using
`mount -o exec /dev/sda5 /media/usrname`
 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the python scripts in scripts directory are trying to modify some other files or directories .... try to trace what it is trying to do...... You have not specified the OS on which u are working ....... see this link https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/issues/22

It says Linux Mint 17 is not supported officially.....